# How to loop through a list of xml files in php

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

Below is my code I want to loop through a list of XML Files and output the nodes of all XML files that are inside.
My following list of XML's is inside a file of xml_joblist.php called :
http://80.08.00.150/internal/xxx/xxxx/xml_joblist.php and inside this url link are the xml file that are listed belowe:

http://80.08.00.150/internal/xxx/xxx/55_27_12116.xml 
http://80.08.00.150/internal/xxx/xxx/55_40_12134.xml 
http://80.08.00.150/internal/xxx/xxx/85_41_12134.xml 
http://80.08.00.150/internal/xxx/xxx/75_43_12134.xml 
http://80.08.00.150/internal/xxx/xxx/58_45_12134.xml

Inside all of them are are the same nodes but with different date like this.

`<PositionRecordInfo>
    <PositionProfile xml:lang="de-DE">Test</PositionProfile></PositionRecordInfo>
<PositionPostings>1</PositionPostings>`

So my question is how to load all the list of XML files one's and output the date from them I have tried something below:

```
public static function parse($content, $pageID) {

    $jobs = array();
    $objects = simplexml_load_string($content, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```

//in $objects is the firs xml_joblist.php objects

```
    if (!isset($objects->Link)) CrawlerHelper::emptyNodeException();
```

//$objects->Link has all the list of links
//here i load the content of first link but i want to load at one's all the content of links ;

```
    $url = (string)$objects->Link[0];
    //$urls=(string)$objects->Link;
    $content = (simplexml_load_file($url));
    //$content = (simplexml_load_file($urls));
    echo json_encode($content) ."\n";
```

//i want to load like this all the contents of xml files.

```
foreach ($content as $job) {
    $jobs=$job->PositionRecordInfo;


        echo $jobs->PositionProfile."\n";


    }
}
```

==> i get an error here => could not load the enitre list of XML-S

Comment: This was the answer:
'$jobs = array();
    $objects = simplexml_load_string($content, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
    $content = (simplexml_load_file($url));
    //$content = (simplexml_load_file($urls));
    echo json_encode($content) ."\n";
'

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
    public static function parse($content, $pageID) {

    $jobs = array();
    $objects = simplexml_load_string($content, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);

    foreach($object->$job as $links)
    {
      $link=all the links;
      //load all the links in a simplexml_load_file
      $job=simplexml_load_file($links);
      //and than put them on array:
      $newjobs=array(JobFiels::url=>$job=>url,and so onee);
      $jobs[]=newjobs;
     } 
      //Test
      echo json_encode($jobs);
      return $jobs;

   }
```